# How to skip sundays (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I don't have any idea how to do it... I need to skip sundays. My query is like

```
SELECT * FROM `table_1` WHERE `date`=(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

but if next day is sunday i need rows from query like this one

```
SELECT * FROM `table_1` WHERE `date`=(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

Any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: You have to write the logic in your code for skip sunday. Are you executing query directly on PHP my admin? in which code you have written this query ?

Comment: Initial interval can never be more than 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put `case` inside the `interval` statement, like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `table_1` 
WHERE `date` = (
    CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL (
        case when dayofweek(current_date + interval 1 day) = 1 then 2 else 1 end
    ) DAY
);
```

Comment: If I understand this query correctly it will work properly only when my SQL server has set 1st day of week as Sunday. I am right?

Comment: I don't think that you can change that. Documentation says that it will start with 1 as sunday. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek

Comment: I found this same and another function WEEKDAY() which has Monday first but with index=0. Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: Good it works for you. And does this `weekday()` with Monday first change that for you?

Comment: No, I can use any of this two functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `CURRENT_DATE` is Saturday and produce the value accordingly.

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table_1` 
WHERE `date`=
  case when dayofweek(current_date) = 7 -- saturday
    then CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 2 DAY
    else CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  end
```